# Return a value from a function in thread in C

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I am new to pthread and I have gone through some tutorials. The tutorials say that I can pass only a single argument to a function used in thread. I solved the problem by using a structure for passing multiple arguments into the thread. But now on further study I came to the conclusion that a function in a thread can't return any value and the only way to do that is the use of global variables. What I actually need is, I need two functions running in two different threads and the return value of one function need to the the input of the other and vice versa. What should I do to implement this need. Thanks in advance. And yes, linux is the platform.

Comment: If one thread needs the return value of the other, then... why need multi-threading? It seems that you could go with a sequence of two operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [`pthread_join()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pthread_join/). It will give value passed to `pthread_exit()`. You can try passing the value to `pthread_exit()` instead of returning from the thread_function.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of a thread is a `void *`.  This can be picked up as the second argument of `pthread_join()`.  See also `pthread_exit()`.